# _tkinter.TclError: bad side: must be top, bottom, left, or right

Tags: python, tkinter

I defined a method for creating a label with the following code,

```
from tkinter import * 

class LoginFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(LoginFrame, self).__init__()

        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()

    # initialize the login screen UI  
    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Login Screen")

        # Set up login frame properties 
        self.parent.title("Login Screen")

        # create a background image 
        photo_bg = PhotoImage(file="building.gif")          
        building = self.make_label(self.parent, image=photo_bg)

        # creating instruction label, where the error occurs
        inst_lbl = self.make_label(self.parent, "Please login to continue")       


    def make_label(parent, caption=NONE, side=TOP, **options):
        label = Label(parent, text=caption, **options)

        if side is not TOP:
            label.pack(side=side)
        else:
            label.pack()

        return label


def main():
    top = Tk()    
    app = LoginFrame(top)
    top.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I got an error when tried to run the code,

```
_tkinter.TclError: bad side "Please login to continue": must be top, bottom, left, or right
```

I am wondering how to resolve the issue? There was no error when creating the back ground image using `make_label`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of `make_label` is missing the `self` parameter. You need to define it as this:

```
def make_label(self, parent, ...):
```